# Ubuntu VPS > restrict openerp for some user

Tags: server, firewall, iptables

In Ubuntu VPS server, `openerp` is running and anyone can using this web interface. my vps server is: `http:// <Public IP>:8069/`.

I want to allow some mac addresses and restrict to all. Here is my `iptables` file:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 80,8069 -m mac --mac-source E0:CA:94:A7:C2:80 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 80,8069 -m mac --mac-source 4C:72:B9:0D:D5:B7 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 80,8069 -j DROP
```

But it's not work. Would you please anyone help me.

What should I do ?

Comment: Are the machines you wish to allow in the same LAN as the server you are shielding?

Comment: As it is public, so i want to restrict from public.only allow mac addresses can see this web interface.is it possible ? how can I do it?

Comment: I got it.I cannot use mac address rules when sources are outside of your internal network. MY vps knows only router mac address and other stations mac adresses which are in the same network. I can add the rules based on IP address.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct answer. I have added it as an answer to your question.

Comment: but how can I secure my web interface of this openerp??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAC based filtering only works for machines in the same LAN. To allow or deny access to machines in remote LANs, use IP-based filtering.